# Rutas en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rutas

tengo la siguiente duda:
Tengo una estructura de directorios asi(components y services estan al mismo nivel dentro de app)

```
app
   components
             shared
                   folder
                         components.ts <- donde lo necesito importar
   services
        servicio_necesario.ts <- que necesito importar
```

en components.ts tengo que hacer el import del servicio
con `import { x,z } from "ruta";`
pero sucede que no me reconoce dando rutas asi: `../../services/servicio_necesario`

¿De que forma puedo acceder al servicio necesario?
como aclaracion en el servicio tengo los export de lo que necesito, pero es la ruta la que necesito realmente.

Comment: El directorio services debería estar dentro de app, como *hermano* de components

Comment: ups, perdon, no le puse el espacio, esta adentro de app al mismo nivel que components, edito

Comment: ¿Usas Visual Studio Code? Lo comento porque se encarga automáticamente de los imports, si quieres... podrías borrar el import y ver si encuentra la clase él solo al autocompletar (Ctrl + Espacio)

Comment: uso ATOM, pero no me reconoce la ruta al buscarla asi

Comment: Sin ver el código no sabría decirte, podrías intentar montar tu escenario en stackblitz.com para estudiarlo

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias por tu respuesta, ya pude solucionarlo, agrege la solucion como respuesta por si a alguien mas le sirve a futuro

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer dos cosas:
`import { ServicioNecesario } from '../../services/servicio-necesario':`

Y luego al interior de la clase del componente:

`constructor (private servicioNecesario: ServicioNecesario){};`

Dentro de tu componente debes utilizar la variable privada servicioNecesario 'servicioNecesario.algunaFuncion()'.

Debes ser un tanto cuidadoso con los nombres de los archivos y de las clases, pues esto tiene definiciones concretas en Angular. Te recomiendo en lugar de guiones bajos usar guiones, los nombres de las clases y servicios siempre empiezan con mayúsculas y de las variables con minúsculas.

Te recomiendo revisar https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Igualmente para crear el servicio puedes utilizar el comando en linea `ng generate service servicio-necesario`.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus respuestas.
Pude solucionar la ruta agregando un tercer `../`
dejandolo de esta forma

```
import { x, z} from '../../../services/servicio_necesario';
```

lo cual tiene sentido viendo que tenia que subir 3 niveles

```
app   -1 <- en este nivel tengo que estar para acceder a services
   components -2
             shared -3
                  folder 
                       components.ts
   services -2
```